# Вопрос по ориентации экрана и UI

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, мобильная-разработка

Как сделать, так, чтобы при переключении на альбомную ориаентацию в игре, отключалась одна Panel, и запустилась другая? Можно ли со скрипта как нибудь обратиться к ориентации экрана? Я прикрепил созданный скрипт ScreenOrient на элемент Panel. В Update  проверил if(Input.deviceOrientation == DevicleOrientation.LandscapeLeft) gameObject.SetActive(false); Но не работает

Comment: А вы пробовали сами что либо сделать, или сразу на SO? Вот к примеру первая ссылка из поисковика по запросу `unity script orientation` - [Screen.orientation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-orientation.html). Я так понимаю, лень? Надо ее перебороть!

Comment: Да, читал, но не получается. Я прикрепил созданный скртпт ScreenOrient на элемент Panel. В Update  проверил if(Input.deviceOrientation == DevicleOrientation.LandscapeLeft) gameObject.SetActive(false);

Comment: Ну тогда наверно ваш вопрос стоит дополнить всей этой информацией, верно? Ведь не только я один могу подумать, что вам просто лень "погуглить"! Вопрос должен содержать в себе как можно больше полезной информации, но только по делу!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь два варианта - первый, вы уже описали, но, видимо, реализовали не совсем правильно:

1. В Update проверять текущую ориентацию и переключать панели при её изменении
2. У `MonoBehaviour` есть метод [OnRectTransformDimensionsChange](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.UIBehaviour.OnRectTransformDimensionsChange.html) - он вызывается, когда меняется размер RectTransform-а, на котором висит класс. Если ваш `Canvas` верхнего уровня прикреплён к камере через режим `Screen Space - Camera`, то при изменении поворота экрана он будет изменять свой размер и вызывать это событие.

Банальная реализация второго способа.
Скрипт должен висеть на самом верхнем в иерархии Canvas:

```
private void Start()
{
    // Этот вызов для того чтобы на старте правильно сориентировать
    OnRectTransformDimensionsChange();
}

private void OnRectTransformDimensionsChange()
{
    if (Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft || Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.LandscapeRight)
    {
        _vertical.SetActive(false);
        _horizontal.SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.Portrait || Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.Portrait)
    {
        _vertical.SetActive(true);
        _horizontal.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Еще вопросик: Вы знаете, как заблочить поворот экрана? Например со скрипта снять галочки с ландшафт left и right в Player settings? Скажем так, if(...){ тут снимается галочка } else autorotate enable(или галочки true становятся). Спасибо

Comment: Ориентация экрана только для чтения да? Я ведь не могу изменить, например если поставил телефон экранов вверх (DeviceOrientation.FaceUp) , то сделать портретным